# How to excute postgre query asynchronously in django

Tags: django, python-3.x, asynchronous

In current scenario result2 not get executed until result1 one finished its execution. I want to execute **select * from Test1** and **select * from Test2** asynchronously.result2 should not wait utile result1 complete its execution.And finally send both the result set to client at a time.

```
def fetchQueryData(request):
        cur=connection.cursor()

        cur.execute("select * from Test1")
        result1=cur.fetchall()
        json1=result1[0][0]

        cur.execute("select * from Test2")
        result2=cur.fetchall()
        json2=result2[0][0]

        cur.close()

        return JsonResponse([json1,json2])
```

Comment: This [blog post](http://techspot.zzzeek.org/2015/02/15/asynchronous-python-and-databases/) might be interesting for you

Comment: django channels

Answer (score 2):

[Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org) can help you with that. You can start asynchronous tasks and wait for them to complete in a while loop. It requires some setting up and additional software on your server though.

To me, it seems that your queries are quite long running. I don't think waiting for them in a single request is the best solution regarding to user experience, but that is probably another topic.